# Error while updating an user email field using process builder and flow

Tags: process-builder, flow

Detail:

i am trying to update the user email using Autolaunched Flow with the help of process builder i am calling flow from process builder and passing values to the flow variable.

The user who is performing the above operation is not having sys admin or modify all permission.

As i know process builder runs in a system mode so the flow also should run in system mode.

[image: Please look into the below error]

Comment: You should get a more detailed email about the error. Are there any additional detail there? Generally when I've seen this error it's been around trying to access a null value from a field.

Comment: but is i am running same flow with system admin i am able to change. i am not getting the email with flow error.

Comment: As system admin are you able to execute on the same record that the above user is failing for?

Comment: Your `Email Deliverability` setting needs to be either `System email only` or `All email`. If it is `No access`, it wouldn't be surprising if that is the error cause in addition to the reason you don't get the error email.

Comment: i have access to change i changed to all email though i am not getting the error mail but test mail i am getting.

Comment: yes same record i am able to update as a system admin

Comment: how i chnage the email Deliverability for the logged in user.

Comment: Email Deliverability is Organization wide. Are you the Owner of the Org, and did you create the Process Builder? I believe Process Builder actually sends the email to the user who created it. Can you check with the person who created it if they got an email?

Comment: i am the owner of snadbox where i am testing and me only created a process builder.

Comment: i checked the monitoring email logs there also i am not getting record sent or failure

Comment: I am not sure that the failure email creates a record in the email log as it is a system email rather than user triggered.

Comment: so what is the best option to check

Comment: Is the field you are trying to update the Email on the actual user account?

Comment: yes but with the help of process builder by  calling autolaunched flow

Comment: it seems like for my sandbox the email Deliverability is disabled for flow i created another normal flow just to test the error mail. i am not getting this one also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an issue with the running user not having access to the field that is being passed to the Process Builder so that the Flow is not able to access the value of the variable that is being passed in.

The Flow error email would be able to clarify how this is failing as it will include the details of the running user and the fields which are not able to be accessed.

Reasons for the field not being able to be updated can be:

1. User has no access to object
2. User has no access to the field
3. Validation rule prevents entry of the data

Comment: i have already given an object level access to the object. modify all for that object.

Comment: i am updating federation id too it's updating without any error, only issue is coming if i am changing the mail id.

Comment: Check the email for the system admin account that owns the flow is correct to make sure the email is going to the right place.

Comment: yes you are correct but i am not getting any mail regarding this error

Comment: test email is coming to me but not from the flow error i checked.